# minimal gnome classic on a mini.iso ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, gui, ubuntu-minimal

I installed ubuntu 12.04 from the mini.iso
I want the most minimal classic gnome possible, all I ever need is a terminal, wireless connection, chromium and mid-night commander. No video or audio players no office no nautilus and no other applications. How can this be achieved? I also don't want a log in graphical interface like GDM or lightdm , I'll be happy to log in using the command line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no gnome-classic without panel, nautilus etc. will you accept an answer "No" for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Just run `sudo apt-get install openbox` or if you want a proper setup replace openbox with lxde.

By the way this isn't GNOME.

Comment: I expected downvote galore.